# Sending an action from a child component and catching it in a parent component

Tags: ember.js

Ember: 1.13.2

I can't seem to get this working.

**Parent/child widget (gridster-container/gridster-widget)**

```
{{#gridster-container}}
    {{#each model as |widget|}}
        {{#gridster-widget sizeX=widget.sizeX sizeY=widget.sizeY action="addWidget"}}

           ...

        {{/gridster-widget}}
    {{/each}}
{{/gridster-container}}
```

**gridster-widget**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName : 'li',
  sizeX : 1,
  sizeY : 1,

  widget : null,

  didInsertElement : function() {
    var sizeX = this.get('sizeX');
    var sizeY = this.get('sizeY');
        //this.get('parentView').addWidget(this, sizeX, sizeY);
    //this.send('addWidget', this, sizeX, sizeY);
    //this.sendAction('action', this, sizeX, sizeY);
    //this.attrs.action(this, sizeX, sizeY);
    //this.get('gridsterContainer').send('addWidget', this, sizeX, sizeY);
    //this.action(this, sizeX, sizeY);
    this.sendAction('action', this, sizeX, sizeY); //I can see this executing in the debugger.
    }

});
```

**In the gridster-container component I have the following action to capture the action.**

```
  actions : {
    addWidget : function(widget, sizeX, sizeY) {
      alert('worked'); //This is never called
    }
  },
```

However the action is never called.

Comment: Are you yielding in the `gridster-container` template? If so the components are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

When you yield you will need to pass the `parentView`so your template becomes:

```
{{#gridster-container as |gridsterContainer|}}
    {{#each model as |widget|}}
        {{#gridster-widget parentView=gridsterContainer sizeX=widget.sizeX sizeY=widget.sizeY action="addWidget"}}

           ...

        {{/gridster-widget}}
    {{/each}}
{{/gridster-container}}
```

Either that or move the `gridster-widget` into `gridster-container.hbs` and then you ll have to pass the model `{{#gridster-container widgets=model}}` and loop over them.

Comment: Not sure why but passing `parentView=gridsterContiner` still didn't work.  I eventually went your second option and passed the widgets directly into the gridster-container.  I set `parent=this` into each widget.  I was then able to do `this.get('parent').send('addWidget',this, sizeX, sizeY)` and it worked.

Comment: @jax I ll give it a try and update the answer, this is untested code might have the syntax wrong atm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment on @Kitler's answer, but this syntax worked for me, with ember 1.13.4:

```
{{#gridster-container as |gridsterContainer|}}
    {{#each model as |widget|}}
        {{#gridster-widget targetObject=gridsterContainer sizeX=widget.sizeX sizeY=widget.sizeY action="addWidget"}}

            ...

        {{/gridster-widget}}
    {{/each}}
{{/gridster-container}}
```

(`targetObject` in place of `parentView`)

As with their answer, this assumes that your `gridster-container.hbs` includes `{{yield this}}`.